# Is programming against Judaism?

Tags: halacha, technology, creation

I just recently learned about this site when I saw Judaism was one of the stack overflow topics. I have been Jewish all my life and two years ago I started programming.

I was wondering if there would be any problems with programming, because when you write computer code you are essentially mimicking Gods creation of the world. You code(say) something and it appears much like how God said "let there be light" and there was light.

Comment: if you are asking whether writing computer code is somehow against jewish law, the answer is "no." if you are asking something else, you might wish to clarify your question.

Comment: user1233418 Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here. Perhaps consider choosing a more meaningful name (unless you have a special attachment to 1233418). I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Jews have a pretty long history of programming and working with computers. Between Feynman and, uh, my dad, I'd say that, regardless of whether programming violates halakha, it doesn't violate Jewish traditions.

Comment: Sorry, know this is old, but had to comment on the phrasing of the question. It makes programming sound like it is the tool of the anti semites :D I think you mean "Is Judaism against Programming" or even better "Does programming go against the Torah"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No. There is no problem with programming in Judaism.
As far as mimicking G-d's creation, we do that all the time: all craftsmen create things. In fact, we are commanded to mimic G-d in certain ways:

[Leviticus 19:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm#2) from Mechon Mamre.

> -קְדֹשִׁים תִּהְיוּ:  כִּי קָדוֹשׁ, אֲנִי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם.
> -Ye shall be holy; for I the LORD your God am holy.

And thanks to DoubleAA for reminding me about:
[Deuteronomy 28:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9992) from Chabad.org

> יְקִימְךָ יְ־הֹוָ־ה לוֹ לְעַם קָדוֹשׁ כַּאֲשֶׁר נִשְׁבַּע לָךְ כִּי תִשְׁמֹר אֶת מִצְוֹת יְ־הֹוָ־ה אֱלֹהֶיךָ וְהָלַכְתָּ בִּדְרָכָיו:
>
> The Lord will establish you as His holy people as He swore to you, if you observe the commandments of the Lord, your God, **and walk in His ways**.

Now, remember that human beings cannot *really* mimic G-d's creation at all. G-d creates from nothing (ex nihilo) while we simply modify and work with things that already exist.

Comment: I'd say you "make," not "create." And, I think it's not merely a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @H3br3w If you're using "create" to mean "ex nihilo" then of course. But that's not the only use of the word. (Semantics)

Comment: Also, is there a specific law against mimicking the creations of God in the first place? I mean, arguably creating an animation of the Genesis account does that, but is that halachically forbidden?

Comment: C.f. R.J.B.Soloveitchik: The first Adam, or "majestic man," employs his creative faculties in order to master his environment as mandated by God. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_Man_of_Faith